# Plotting heatmap with available attributes instead of range D3 React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js, heatmap

I'm working on a heatmap which basically plots the graph between taxIDs and KeywordNames from an external JSON. While I'm able to plot the values I see many blank spaces on the graph and clueless how I can plot them with the available data.

Here's the link to codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/40mnzk9xv4

On the X-Axis I'm plotting the TaxIDs which are being calculated within the given range. I did try using the function `rangeBands()` but I get an error everytime.

Its the similar case with Y-Axis where I'am plotting the keywordIDs which are also being calculated within a range. I'm trying to print all the KeywordNames on Y axis and all taxIDs on the X-Axis and plot their corresponding spectracount on graph.

Please help me where have I gone wrong.

The output I'm looking for is something similar to this: https://bl.ocks.org/Bl3f/cdb5ad854b376765fa99

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some things to help you get you one your way:

First, your scales should use `scaleBand()`, not `scaleLinear()`, as they have discrete domains (i.e. categories of something, rather than continuous)

Second, your scale domains is taking every value of `taxId` and `keywordName` in your data as a possible value. But some values are repeated more than once. You need to be filtering them so you only have unique values. So your scale code should be:

```
const xValues = d3.set(data.map(d => d.taxId)).values();
const yValues = d3.set(data.map(d => d.keywordName)).values();
const xScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .domain(xValues); //X-Axis

const yScale = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, height])
    .domain(yValues); //Y-Axis
```

Finally, your code that places the heatmap tiles needs to be calling the scale functions so it works out the position of each rect correctly:

```
  chart.selectAll('g')
    .data(data).enter().append('g')
    .append('rect')
    .attr('x', d => { return xScale(d.taxId) })
    .attr('y', d => { return yScale(d.keywordName) })
```

That should get you most of the way there. You'll want to also reduce `cellSize` and remove the `tickFormat` calls on the axes as they are trying to convert your text labels to numbers.

Comment: Many thanks for the above code. It helped me in getting the expected output.

Comment: Hello, I want to know if there is any function or syntax where I can get a color instead of white spaces in my heat map? I mean where there is no relationship between the taxonomy and keyword it shows up a white space but instead I need a color could anyone help me in this?---- Thank you